# Archlinux : golang can't use go build

Tags: go

i installed archlinux few days ago, and i want to configure golang but there is some problem,
I installed go from pacman :

```
pacman -S go
```

and i export some env var in my .bashrc

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/go
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
```

But when i build with "go build" i've got the error message :

```
main.go:11:2: no buildable Go source files in /usr/lib/go/src/go
```

`go env` includes:

```
GOBIN="/home/thomas/go/bin" GOEXE="" GOPATH="/home/thomas/go" GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error message it seems like you might be trying to import the "go" package in `main.go` on line 11.

Removing that import statement should fix the problem.